# Wordpress - SFTP - PDF to Download not open in browser?

Tags: wordpress, pdf

Hello & Thank you for your help, here my question :

How would I go about making a PDF file to download in browser rather than opening
my set up is wordpress & the file is on the SFTP (would like to do that without plugin), please be explicit as I am learning ... & a bit old ;))

Cheers ,

P_001

Comment: you can try adding the `download` tag to your download links, ex: `<a href="LINK" download>Download</a>`

Answer (score 0):

The below should do it: Just change the `href="link"`, `download=""`, and the text you want to be displayed

```
<a href="http://www.mywebsite.com/folder/that/contains/my/pdf/filename.pdf" download="pdf.pdf">Link to Download PDF</a>
```

Just play around with it you should be able to get your head around it, it's not too complicated.